# What word means "someone who ignores emotion in the face of pain"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word means "someone who ignores their own emotion in the face of their pain"? (Does it start with C?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word *stoic* comes to mind:

> **stoic** |ˈstō-ik|
>   *noun*
>   1 a person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining.

[From NOAD]

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are looking for *composed*.

There's also:

- Dispassionate
- Staid
- Poised
- Stoic

Answer (score 1):

Could be 'Spartan', or just'unemotional'.